# SSRS - Textbox Values doesn't apply to othe pages

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has a couple textboxes on them, they are large in size (48 pt font).

The report works perfectly if one record is returned from the query but if a query returns multiple records we'll get the correct number of pages back but only page 1 will have data, the rest are just blank.

The only solution we found is if we reduce the font size of the textbox to a very small number it works correctly but that's not a working solution.

In case you need to know, I'm using Report builder 3 and SQL Server 2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, some items were getting buried under content, I readjusted the layout and it works perfectly now.